# R optimize linear function

Tags: r, optimization

I'm new to R and need a little help with a simple optimization.

I want to apply a functional transformation to a variable (`sales_revenue`) over time (24 month forecast values 1 to 24). Basically I want to push sales revenue for products from later months into earlier month.

The functional transformations on `t` time is:

```
trans=D+(t/(A+B*t+C*t^2))
```

I will then want to solve:

1) sales_revenue=sales_revenue*trans

where `total_sales_revenue=1,000,000` (or within +/- 2.5%)

`total_sales_revenue` is the sum of all `sales_revenue` over the 24 months forecast.

If trans has too many parameters I can fix most of them if required and leave B free to estimate.

I think the approach should be fix all parameters except `B`, differentiate function (1) (not sure what ti diff by) and solve for a non zero minima (use constraints to make sure its the right minima and no-zero, run optimization on that function with the constraint that the total sum of `sales_revenue*trans` will be equal (or close to) 1,000,000.

Comment: Did you try to use `optim` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am looking at optim now, just working through the syntax. Was after a leg up if anyone had done anything similiar before.

Comment: I should have set that as fixed to about .85 as the function without this is bounded between 0 and 1 and I want it to be able to apply a proportion above 1 early in the time series and then below 1 later in the time series. optimizing manually .85 works well so far. Have a good idea for values for the rest and should only need to estimate B which determines the height of the peak of the function.

Comment: BTW, t isn't the best variable name since t is a function in R.

Comment: Can you supply a minimal reproducible example with data? Preferably showing your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

@user2138362, did you mean "1) sales_revenue=total_sales_revenue*trans"?

I'm supposing your parameters `A`, `C` and `D` are fixed, and you want to find `B` such that the distance between your observed values and your predicted values is minimized.

Let's say your time is in months. So we can write a function to give you the squared distance:

```
dist <- function(B)
{
t <- 1:length(sales_revenue)

total_sales_revenue <- sum(sales_revenue)

predicted <- total_sales_revenue * (D+(t/(A+B*t+C*t^2)))

sum((sales_revenue-predicted)^2)
}
```

I'm also using the squared euclidean distance as a measure of distance. Make the appropriate changes if that is not the case.

Now, `dist` is the function you have to minimize. You can use `optim`, as pointed out by @iTech. But even at the minimum of `dist` it probably won't be zero, as you have many (24) observations. But you can get the best fit, plot it, and see if it's nice.